# What's the quickest/cheapest way to get URL rewriting implemented?

Tags: url-rewriting, automation

Related to [another question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/336/do-keyword-based-filenames-and-urls-really-matter/) - if you need to get URL rewriting implemented ASAP, what are some methods that you've used or know of that can speed this up?

Comment: I don't understand this question. The way you do it depends on what webserver you are using. "Quickest" - well whatever way works with your webserver. "Cheapest" - you want a list of services of people who'll do it for you?

Comment: Cheapest and Quickest usually relate to the same thing if you're a webmaster because time == money. This is about fast-tracking url-writing implementations if you're not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We managed to do several hundred products in under 8 hours. Here was our scenario:

We had:

- Dog ugly URLs that were filled with meaningless parameters
- In-house developers
- Full access to the SQL database and schema
- IIS6/[ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) (but we could have done this for others)

### Option 1

Our products table looked like this:

```
ID | Product Name | Description | etc
-------------------------------------
001|Product 1     | This is...  | etc
002|Product 1     | This is...  | etc
003|Product 1     | This is...  | etc
```

So we wrote a small batch program that would loop through our `products` table and create entries in our `httpd.ini` file (ISAPI Rewrite's version of `.htaccess`), so that we ended up with a file with hundreds of entries like this:

`RewriteRule (/product-1/) /DLLFolder/Requester.dll?APPLICATION=MyApp&PROGRAM=Products&ARGUMENTS=-N001 [I,O,U]`
<sub>* Please see disclaimer</sub>

Our products don't change very often, so we just re-run this manually each time we added something. Not elegant, but this is about getting it done quick/cheap.

Then, everywhere that our links were printed to products, we just made sure that the links were outputted to their full URL.

This took about 8 hours in total.

### Option 2

A single generic URL Rewriting rule that looks something like this:

`RewriteRule (/products/)(.*/)(.*) /DLLFolder/Requester.dll?APPLICATION=MyApp&PROGRAM=Products&ARGUMENTS=-N$3 [I,O,U]`
<sub>* Please see disclaimer</sub>

This meant we could write:

`/products/my/thing/whatever/the/hell/i/want/123`

And it would rewrite to the correct URL. Then it's just a matter of changing the output of your URL links.

<sub>* **DISCLAIMER**: My regex skills are very rusty and I made those up on the spot. They may be wrong. Your milage on the actual regex's may vary, but the concept still stands.</sub>